# Fortran : generic procedure of parent is called instead of child when allocating child from class of parent

Tags: oop, generics, inheritance, fortran

I explain my question in the form of an example.

I have a type (location2d_t) which includes two members `x`, and `y` and  a type-bound procedure (`calcdist2d`). The procedure, in addition of (`this`) with class of (`location2d_t`), accepts its own type (as second dummy argument) to calculate a distance.
Now, I go further and extend the type to (`location3d_t`) which has `z` as well.

To re-define  the procedure, I cannot override the previous one so I create a new procedure (`calcdist3d`) with the second argument of type of (`location3d_t`) and make a generic procedure (`calcdist`) for them. In other words, second arguments have different types so generic idea is applicable.

In a more general scope, let's say main program here, for the sake of generality I declare my object as class of parent. When I allocate the object with type of child (`location3d_t`), a call to (`calcdist`) whose second dummy argument is (`location3d_t`) refers to parent generic and says

```
Error: Found no matching specific binding for the call to the GENERIC 'calcdist'
```

The code is

```
module point_mod
implicit none
type location2d_t
    integer :: x,y
contains
    procedure :: calcdist2d => calcdistance2d
    procedure :: here => here_location2d
    generic   :: calcdist => calcdist2d 
end type

type, extends(location2d_t) :: location3d_t
    integer :: z
contains
    procedure :: calcdist3d => calcdistance3d
    procedure, public :: here => here_location3d
    generic, public   :: calcdist =>   calcdist3d 
end type        

contains

function calcdistance2d(this,location) result(output)
    class(location2d_t) :: this
    type(location2d_t)  :: location
    integer :: output
    output = int(sqrt(real((location%x-this%x)**2+(location%y-this%y)**2)))
end function

function calcdistance3d(this,location) result(output)
    class(location3d_t) :: this
    type(location3d_t) :: location
    integer :: output
    output = int(sqrt(real((location%x-this%x)**2+ &
    (location%y-this%y)**2+(location%z-this%z)**2)))
end function

subroutine here_location2d(this)
    class (location2d_t) :: this
    print*, "we are in locationd2d_t"
end subroutine

subroutine here_location3d(this)
    class (location3d_t) :: this
    print*, "we are in locationd3d_t"
end subroutine
end module
```

The module is compiled without any error. The below program is implemented to use the module:

```
program main
use point_mod
implicit none

class (location2d_t), allocatable :: loc
type (location3d_t) :: dum

allocate(location2d_t::loc)
call loc%here() ! calls  location2d_t procedure

deallocate(loc)

allocate(location3d_t::loc)
call loc%here() !correctly calls procedure of location3d_t 

print*,loc%calcdist(dum) ! gives error

select type (loc)
type is (location3d_t)
   print*,loc%calcdist(dum) ! runs well
end select    

end program
```

The procedure "Here" finds its dynamic type correctly. Why isn't generic procedure of child (calcdist) explicitly called ? Do I have to use "select type" block always even in this obvious case?
N.B.: I checked the code with GNU fortran 4.8 and 4.9, and ifort 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use "select type". Outside the "type is"  block, `loc`  is polymorphic. Only inside `type is (location3d_t)`, `loc` has a type and can be passed as dummy argument with defined type.

Generic procedures are always not overridden when the type is extended, so in `location3d_t`, `calcdist` is the generic binding for `calcdist3d` and `calcdist2d` and `loc` needs a specific type when calling `calcdist` to find the appropriate procedure.

When `location2d_t` is extended, to `location3d_t`, `here` binding is overriden and there is only one procedure associated to `loc%here()` so can be called outside the "type is"  block

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems annoying to use "Type is" block in all branches of parent while each one can easily use its own generic procedure. Do you know any reference regarding this behaviour of generic procedures?

Comment: You can find some information about resolving generic procedures in:  _"The Fortran 2003 Handbook"_, Chapter 12.5.4.1 "Generic Procedure Names"

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this behavior without generics with only a slight tweak to your `calcdistanceXd` functions.  The reason you couldn't override the function in your extended type is that the argument type of `location` was mismatched.  If you instead declare `location` in `calcdistance2d` to be `class(location2d_t)` then you can match this in `calcdistance3d`.  You will have to add in a `select type` construct into `calcdistance3d` in order to access the members of `location3d_t` from the polymorphic variable `location`.

Example:

```
module point_mod
  implicit none

  type :: location2d_t
    integer :: x, y
  contains
    procedure, public, pass(this) :: calcdist => calcdistance2d
    procedure, public, pass(this) :: here => here_location2d
  end type

  type, extends(location2d_t) :: location3d_t
    integer :: z
  contains
    procedure, public, pass(this) :: calcdist => calcdistance3d
    procedure, public, pass(this) :: here => here_location3d
  end type
contains

  function calcdistance2d(this, location) result(output)
    class(location2d_t) :: this
    class(location2d_t)  :: location
    integer :: output
        output = int(sqrt(real((location%x-this%x)**2+(location%y-this%y)**2)))
  end function

  function calcdistance3d(this,location) result(output)
    class(location3d_t) :: this
    class(location2d_t) :: location
    integer :: output
    select type (location)
      type is (location3d_t)
        output = int(sqrt(real((location%x-this%x)**2+ &
        (location%y-this%y)**2+(location%z-this%z)**2)))
      class default 
        output = -1
    end select
  end function

  subroutine here_location2d(this)
    class (location2d_t) :: this
    print*, "we are in locationd2d_t"
  end subroutine

  subroutine here_location3d(this)
    class (location3d_t) :: this
    print*, "we are in locationd3d_t"
  end subroutine
end module
```

With this version of `point_mod`, your example program works:

```
program main
  use point_mod
  implicit none
  class (location2d_t), allocatable :: loc
  type (location3d_t) :: dum

  allocate(location2d_t::loc)
  call loc%here() ! calls  location2d_t procedure

  deallocate(loc)

  allocate(location3d_t::loc)
  call loc%here() !correctly calls procedure of location3d_t 

  print*,loc%calcdist(dum) 

end program
```

It is true this approach still requires a `select type`, but it is hidden in the module implementation rather than being required by users of the module.

Comment: You are right.I have to change my style of programming to this. Thanks.